# Appropriate statistics for proportions where categories are composites of independent binary variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, proportion

I have data in the form of three digit binary numbers (i.e. 100, 101, etc.) scored for each individual in my samples taken from two populations I wish to compare. The three numbers represent independent states but I'm interested in comparing the occurrence of particular patterns (e.g. does 110 occur more in one population than the other?). However, the states themselves are not entirely independent because they represent *changes* from the original state. Every member of both population is derived from a population with the same state (actually 100) and so occurrences of states different from 100 indicate that a change has occurred and any state that differs in more than one digit has undergone more than one change, meaning that the categories I'm interested in are not wholly independent (i.e. the existence of individuals with score 101 makes the existence of individuals with 111 more likely).

What I want to know is whether this matters in terms of the statistical analysis? Can I compare the categories I'm interested (100, 000, 110, and anything ending in 1) using the same statistical tests I'd normally use for comparing proportions or do I need to use something different? Is the same true for the calculation of confidence intervals for the observed proportions?

If it helps, the actual science is this: I'm working on phase variation in bacteria, which is a particular form of mutation. These mutations are reversible, affect particular genes and occur with very high frequency. For each gene of interest the mutation can switch between an on state and an off state. We score the current state of the genes - i.e. the genotype - as short binary values, so with three genes we might score a colony as 100, meaning the first gene is on, and the second is off and third is off. I am comparing the state of the genes in two bacterial populations, one treated, one control to see whether particular genotypes occur more often in the treated population than the control and whether the differences in the occurrence of each of these particular genotypes is significant (which would suggest that the population had undergone selection). The control (original) population is scored 100, and the interesting genotypes are 100, 110, 000, and any genotype ending with a 1 (i.e. 001, 101, etc.). Any genotype with more than one difference from the original genotype (i.e. 110, 011, etc.) must have had more than one mutation occur.

Comment: So basically this is a study over two time periods.  At time "zero" all units are $100$ and at time "one" units could be any one of $8$ different values $(000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111)$.  You want to analyse and compare the distribution of your two populations across each of the $8$ values at time "one".  The tricky part for you is that many transitions between the $8$ values could potentially occur between times "zero" and "one" (eg 100 to 101 to 111 to 110 to 100), so you may see/miss differences just because of the timing of your sample.  Is this correct?

Comment: No, not quite. The problem is that transitions are not entirely independent so a change from 100->110 is much more likely than a change from 100->111 but a change from 110->111 is (probably) exactly as likely as a change from 100->101, so once a population contains members of type 110, the formation of members with type 111 becomes much more likely. This, I think, means that the _proportion_ of the final population that are of type 111 is not independent of the proportion of type 110.